# how to display the Event output reversly in C#?

Tags: c#, events

when i am executing following code it executes the output from 2/feb/12, i want to display the output from today date and then yesterday, then day before yesterday.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace @event
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    class MySample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string eventLogName = "System";
            string sourceName = "BTHUSB";
            string machineName =".";
            EventLog eventLog;
            eventLog = new EventLog();
            eventLog.Log = eventLogName;
            eventLog.Source = sourceName;
            eventLog.MachineName = machineName;
            int i;
            i = 0;

            foreach (EventLogEntry log in eventLog.Entries)
            {
                i = i + 1;
                if(log.EntryType.ToString()=="Error")
                Console.WriteLine((i)+") Entry type: {0} , Category: {1},  Data: {2}, ID: {3}, Source: {4} \n",log.EntryType,log.TimeWritten.ToLocalTime(),log.Data,log.EventID,log.Source);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

please help me to fix this problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple call to [Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb358497.aspx) will do it:

```
foreach (var log in eventLog.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Reverse()) {...}
```

Comment: sorry that option is not available, can you suggest another

Comment: @Gomathipriya Answer updated - the Reverse method is available on `IEnumerable<T>`, the call to `Cast<EventLogEntry>` ensures this method is available